# Can't select numerical values from database into a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2003

I want to use a combobox to retrieve data from an access database, but it doesn't work with numerical values.

This part of the code is the connection string and object:

```
public partial class StockControl : Form
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    public StockControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Folder\NewStockControl.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    }
```

Here is the code I used to retrieve the field ProductName in the Access database (StockControl is the name of the form I created):

```
private void StockControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select ProductName from Products";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cbProductId.Items.Add(reader["ProductName"].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }

    }
```

And here is the code I added to the combo box (cbProductId)

```
private void cbProductId_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "SELECT * from Products WHERE ProductName='"+cbProductId.Text+"'";
            command.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                txtStockName.Text = reader["ProductName"].ToString();
                txtStockQty.Text= reader["SupplyLeft"].ToString();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
    }
```

There are two textboxes in the StockControl form: txtStockName and txtStockQty, and I want the fields ProductName and SupplyLeft to be displayed in those textboxes respectively. However whenever I run the code the only value that shows is ProductName, but SupplyLeft doesn't. I assume it has to do with the fact that it is an integer rather than a string, but I don't know how to convert the text box to be able to display the value SupplyLeft.

Comment: `cbProductId.Text`  Try `cbProductId.SelectedItem.ToString()` instead.  Use parameters to avoid SQL injection and formatting errors.  If you know it's only one row being returned, prefer `if (reader.Read())` to `while (reader.Read())`  Code should work otherwise.  Use the debugger to inspect the values.

Comment: We can't answer this unless you post query result as if you execute it in query editor....*"I assume it has to do with the fact that it is an integer rather than a string,"* - no at all. Here you have an issue : `while (reader.Read())` If you display a single result in text box, what is happening - if you have multiple rows, you endup displaying last one as it returned from the query. Your answer lies in my first sentence

Comment: @T.S. I'm confused. I'm a beginner on this so I'm not sure how a lot of stuff works. How do you mean post "query result as if you execute it in query editor"? I haven't used the query editor, only the coding bits

Comment: @LarsTech I've tried it and still doesn't work :(

Comment: I can't see what you tried.  It could be that the query is correct: you don't have a SupplyLeft value for that product in the database.

Comment: You need to execute `SELECT * from Products WHERE ProductName = '"+cbProductId.Text+"'` directly in the query window in MS Access. And see the results.Only you replace `cbProductId` with actual value `ProductName = 'your  product id'`. When you see the resultset, you will see why your text box is empty. Also, if your product id is number, you don't add single quotes in WHERE. This is why your question is not answerable. You simply have not posted relevant information. Like DB resultset and content of `command.CommandText`